# iOS Core-Plot scroll doesn't work well

Tags: ios, core-plot

Using CorePlot version 1.6.
Running iOS 8.3.

I'm using Core-Plot with ScatterPlot for to represent multiples lines.
When I scroll, the graph moves to jumps and it locks. I don't know what happens. Can you help me?
Here my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
@interface TemporalLineViewController:UIViewController<CPTPlotDataSource,
CPTScatterPlotDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView;

@end


@interface TemporalLineViewController (){
    NSMutableDictionary *dates;
}
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSArray *plotData;
@end

@implementation TemporalLineViewController
-(CPTGraph *)createGraph{
   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewGraph.frame.origin.x, viewGraph.frame.origin.y, 500, viewGraph.frame.size.height)];

    CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:hostingView.bounds];
    [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTSlateTheme]];
    hostingView.hostedGraph=graph;

    // Axes
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromDouble(ONEDAY);
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0);
    x.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    CPTTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[CPTTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
    timeFormatter.referenceDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
    x.labelFormatter            = timeFormatter;
    x.labelRotation             = CPTFloat(M_PI_4);

    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.hidden=YES;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromInt(0);
    return graph;
}

-(void)createScatterPlot{

    CPTGraph * graph = [self createGraph];

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    NSTimeInterval xLow       = 0.0;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xLow) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(ONEDAY * 10.0)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(-1) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(5.0)];
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
    plotSpace.allowsMomentum = YES;

    CPTScatterPlot *diagnosticPlot = [self createScatterPlotWithIdentifier:DIAGNOSTIC_PLOT withLineColor:[CPTColor greenColor] withFillColor:[CPTColor greenColor]];
    CPTScatterPlot *vaccinePlot = [self createScatterPlotWithIdentifier:VACCINE_PLOT withLineColor:[CPTColor blackColor] withFillColor:[CPTColor blackColor]];
    CPTScatterPlot *interventionPlot = [self createScatterPlotWithIdentifier:INTERVENTION_PLOT withLineColor:[CPTColor blueColor] withFillColor:[CPTColor blueColor]];
    CPTScatterPlot *smokingHabitPlot = [self createScatterPlotWithIdentifier:SMOKING_HABIT_PLOT withLineColor:[CPTColor yellowColor] withFillColor:[CPTColor yellowColor]];
    CPTScatterPlot *menstrualPlot = [self createScatterPlotWithIdentifier:MENSTRUAL_PLOT withLineColor:[CPTColor redColor] withFillColor:[CPTColor redColor]];
    CPTScatterPlot *menstrualTreatmentPlot = [self createScatterPlotWithIdentifier:MENSTRUAL_TREATMENT_PLOT withLineColor:[CPTColor orangeColor] withFillColor:[CPTColor orangeColor]];
    CPTScatterPlot *psychomotorMilestonePlot = [self createScatterPlotWithIdentifier:PSYCHOMOTOR_MILESTONE_PLOT withLineColor:[CPTColor purpleColor] withFillColor:[CPTColor purpleColor]];

    [graph addPlot:vaccinePlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    [graph addPlot:diagnosticPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    [graph addPlot:interventionPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    [graph addPlot:smokingHabitPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    [graph addPlot:menstrualPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    [graph addPlot:menstrualTreatmentPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    [graph addPlot:psychomotorMilestonePlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];   
}

-(CPTScatterPlot *)createScatterPlotWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withLineColor:(CPTColor *)lineColor withFillColor:(CPTColor *) fillColor{
    CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = identifier;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    lineStyle.lineWidth              = 3.0;
    lineStyle.lineColor              = lineColor;
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
    CPTPlotSymbol *plotSymbol2 = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    plotSymbol2.fill               = [CPTFill fillWithColor:fillColor];
    plotSymbol2.size               = CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0);
    dataSourceLinePlot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol2;

    return dataSourceLinePlot;
}

-(void)generateData{
    NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray array];

    [data addObject:[self createDiagnosticData]];
    [data addObject:[self createVaccineData]];
    [data addObject:[self createInterventionData]];
    [data addObject:[self createSmokingHabitData]];
    [data addObject:[self createMenstrualData]];
    [data addObject:[self createMenstrualTreatmentData]];
    [data addObject:[self createPsychomotorMilestoneData]];
    self.plotData = data;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Plot Data Source Methods

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfRecordsForPlot");
    if ([plot.identifier isEqual:DIAGNOSTIC_PLOT]) {
        NSMutableArray *data = self.plotData[0];
        return data.count;
    }else if([plot.identifier isEqual:VACCINE_PLOT]){
        NSMutableArray *data = self.plotData[1];
        return data.count;
    } else if([plot.identifier isEqual:INTERVENTION_PLOT]){
        NSMutableArray *data = self.plotData[2];
        return data.count;
    } else if([plot.identifier isEqual:SMOKING_HABIT_PLOT]){
        NSMutableArray *data = self.plotData[3];
        return data.count;
    } else if([plot.identifier isEqual:MENSTRUAL_PLOT]){
        NSMutableArray *data = self.plotData[4];
        return data.count;
    } else if([plot.identifier isEqual:MENSTRUAL_TREATMENT_PLOT]){
        NSMutableArray *data = self.plotData[5];
        return data.count;
    } else if([plot.identifier isEqual:PSYCHOMOTOR_MILESTONE_PLOT]){
        NSMutableArray *data = self.plotData[6];
        return data.count;
    }
    return 0;
}

-(id)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"numberForPlot");
    if ([plot.identifier isEqual:DIAGNOSTIC_PLOT]) {
        NSMutableArray *data = self.plotData[0];
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(data[index][@(fieldEnum)])];
        if ([str intValue]==0) {
            return nil;
        }
        return data[index][@(fieldEnum)];
    }else if([plot.identifier isEqual:VACCINE_PLOT]){
        NSMutableArray *data = self.plotData[1];
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(data[index][@(fieldEnum)])];
        return data[index][@(fieldEnum)];
    }else if([plot.identifier isEqual:INTERVENTION_PLOT]){
        NSMutableArray *data = self.plotData[2];
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(data[index][@(fieldEnum)])];
        return data[index][@(fieldEnum)];
    }else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:SMOKING_HABIT_PLOT]) {
        NSMutableArray *data = self.plotData[3];
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(data[index][@(fieldEnum)])];
        if ([str intValue]==0) {
            return nil;
        }
        return data[index][@(fieldEnum)];
    }else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:MENSTRUAL_PLOT]) {
        NSMutableArray *data = self.plotData[4];
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(data[index][@(fieldEnum)])];
        if ([str intValue]==0) {
            return nil;
        }
        return data[index][@(fieldEnum)];
    }else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:MENSTRUAL_TREATMENT_PLOT]) {
        NSMutableArray *data = self.plotData[5];
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(data[index][@(fieldEnum)])];
        if ([str intValue]==0) {
            return nil;
        }
        return data[index][@(fieldEnum)];
    }else if([plot.identifier isEqual:PSYCHOMOTOR_MILESTONE_PLOT]){
        NSMutableArray *data = self.plotData[6];
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(data[index][@(fieldEnum)])];
        return data[index][@(fieldEnum)];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Finally I found. In my case my view controller is in slide view controller and slide view has pan gesture. That pan gesture was conflicting with scroll. So, if anybody is suffering from such issues then look for gestures or any custom touch event handling.

Answer (score 0):

Have you reset your scroll view's content size ? If not then reset it to ScatterPlot's frame size **if that is only view inside scroll view**.

Comment: I don't have a scroll view. The scroll is own of the ScatterPlot.

Comment: Then au you try that to include into UIScrollView ? Or change the frame of scatter plot so that it can get accommodate into your frame bounds.

Comment: I don't want to include it into UIScrollView. The graph shows well, the zoom work well but when I do scroll to other side, the scroll graph stop it.